# codeigniter active record nested query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm having a problem converting below MySQL code to a Codeigniter active record query.

```
SELECT sss.*, c.country_name, c.country_code 
  FROM ( SELECT gr.* 
           FROM (`be_goldrate` as `gr`) 
          WHERE `gr`.`country_id` != 0 
            AND `gr`.`rate_type` = 'calculated' 
           ORDER BY gr.date DESC ) as sss 
   LEFT JOIN `be_countries` as `c` 
     ON `c`.`country_id`=`sss`.`country_id`  
   GROUP BY `sss`.`country_id`
```

I've tried as suggested [here](http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/) but without success.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: you might want to make an sql view of: SELECT gr.* 
           FROM (`be_goldrate` as `gr`) 
          WHERE `gr`.`country_id` != 0 
            AND `gr`.`rate_type` = 'calculated' 
           ORDER BY gr.date DESC ) ? to increase performance?

Comment: @joelharkes no it is to get latest be_goldreate's data

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't support subqueries natively.  If you want, you can try my subquery library, it should let you do what you want.  https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries

Comment: CI 3.0 will have subquery (or "grouping") supported.

Comment: You'll either have to use ->query() method without active records, or manually editing the mysql driver to include "compile_select()" & the hot-fix for ->from() method from CI 3 to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check the [Codeigniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

```
     $this->db->select('sss.*, c.country_name, c.country_code ');
       $this->db->from('(SELECT gr.* 
       FROM (`be_goldrate` as `gr`) 
      WHERE `gr`.`country_id` != 0 
        AND `gr`.`rate_type` = "calculated" 
       ORDER BY gr.date DESC) as sss');
       $this->db->join('be_countries as c','c.country_id = sss.country_id','left');

       $this->db->group_by('sss.country_id');
```

please report if any error

Comment: You should put `()` around the subquery in the `from`.