# How to write multiple subqueries in Active recorde Codeigniter way?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$levelsql =$this->db->query("SELECT pro_id,pro_xp,pro_label
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *, 
        (
          SELECT SUM(pro_xp)
            FROM tbl_program
            WHERE pro_xp <= t.pro_xp
        ) total
        FROM tbl_program t
    ) q
   WHERE total <= $ProfileXp
   ORDER BY pro_xp desc");
```

I wrote this query using CI function but want it to be written in Active records way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subquery in codeigniter active record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047149/subquery-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703992/codeigniter-active-record-nested-query

Comment: Thanks for reply @FastSnail & GopaThemes . I have checked both links you've suggested. But it's not strict active record way of doing. Can you guys have any idea how can i do it that way. ? without writing full query as subquery.